# Bad mouse cursor offset in visual studio itself

Tags: visual-studio

I have something really weird going on and don't know where the problem lies..

I recently started working on a Lenovo X1 Carbon with touchscreen. When working with the touchpad or external mouse there seems to be some kind of a bad offset when clicking inside my visual studio working pane.

I have to click on the row above to get my cursor to be set on the row below. This ONLY happens in Visual Studio's working pane.

I need to click on the red square to get my cursor on the place it is in the picture and I have NO idea how to fix this :-( I couldn't find any problem like this on the web.

[image]

I'm working in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on a brand new system with all drivers up to date. Running Windows 10 enterprise on a UHD display, so my DPI is set at 200% and perhaps the problem lies here...

Comment: Have you tried setting the DPI in Windows to 96 (or 100%) and try if it works normally?

Comment: Are you using multiple displays or only the built-in screen?

Comment: I just tested VS2015 at 200% display scaling - no problems.

Comment: Working on laptop display without external screen attached right now. I must say... I'm currently in doubt if this happens when working on my external display (can't test it right now).

Comment: I've tested on 100% dpi before and it was the same.. but I signed off and on right now at 100% and it does work fine now. Too bad it's impossible to work like this.. wayyy to small to work properly :-(

Comment: However...  I'll work on 100% for now and simply zoom in. The menu and all the rest is tiny but it'll do for now

Comment: Really strange. As far as I know the Visual Studio IDE is built on WPF since VS 2010 and has built-in support for high-dpi displays since then. I have worked with VS 2012, 2013 and 2015 on high-dpi laptops (3200x1800 px @ 15", 2160x1440 px @ 12") without any problems. I work with a display sclaing of 150 %, but higher values should also work.

Comment: I had a similar issue - visual studio acted as if I clicked a few dozen pixels to the right of where I actually clicked (it often selected something from the Solution Explorer when I click something in the Search box in the top right of the main window). But ONLY on my external monitor. DPI setting change (both screens to 100%) seems to have fixed it. Thanks.